# Debug Metro Application using Windbg

Tags: microsoft-metro, windbg

I'm trying to debug a C++ Metro App using Windbg. Since Windbg executes in desktop, the application gets suspended after 5 seconds of debug session and I have to switch back to the Metro Desktop to resume the application.

Is there a way to debug an Metro Application using Windbg and not suspending it.

Comment: Try running windbg and metro app side by side. Follow this http://www.tomsguide.com/us/win8-tips-tricks,review-1778-11.html

Comment: Try this link .. http://www.thomgerdes.com/2011/12/debugging-metro-style-applications.html

Answer (score 0):

For future reference -- PLMDebug.exe /disableDebug [name of package] is the way to achieve this. Details about the executable located here: [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/jj680085(v=vs.85).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/jj680085%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)